# Reading a text file and processing it line by line

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a text file i want my program to :

1 - display number of lines and file path .

2 - loop through each line .

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\\test.txt");
```

**Edited (The Answer)**

```
public static string[] local_file; // make a string array to load the file into it
int i = 0; // index of lines 
  try 
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog // use OpenFileDialog to choose your file
        {
            Filter = "Combos file (*.txt)|*.txt" ;// select only text files
        }
        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            local_file= File.ReadAllLines(op.FileName);// load all the contents of the file into the array 

            string count = "lines = " + Convert.ToString(local_file.Length); // number of lines 

            string file_name = op.FileName; // show the file name including the path
        }
        for (i; i < local_file.Length; i++)// loop through each line 
            {
             // do something here remember to use local_file[i] for the lines
            }

    }catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
```

Comment: please show the part of the code where you check the actual line for 'ali' (where is your Loop? Why .FirstOrDefault?)

Comment: You get all the lines but then only look at the first one (`FirstOrDefault`)- why are you expecting it to read any more than the first line? This seems like a very basic question that suggests a general lack of knowledge of the language rather than a specific problem...

Comment: Professor Google will be happy to tell you about "c-sharp how to read text from a text file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static string[] local_file; // make a string array to load the file into it
 int i = 0; // index of lines 
 try 
        {
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog // use OpenFileDialog to choose your file
            {
                Filter = "Combos file (*.txt)|*.txt" ;// select only text files
            }
            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                local_file= File.ReadAllLines(op.FileName);// load all the contents of the file into the array 

                string count = "lines = " + Convert.ToString(local_file.Length); // number of lines 

                string file_name = op.FileName; // show the file name including the path
            }
            for (i; i < local_file.Length; i++)// loop through each line 
                {
                 // do something here remember to use local_file[i] for the lines
                }

        }catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @TomAranda That's why i answerd it using comments , to help others understand no just copy the code

Comment: Okay.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Make it easy by filtering the lines which contains name ali.
Later you can user foreach to split each line if lines.count is more than 0.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Test.txt").Where(l => l.Contains("ali"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(".....");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("...."))
            { 
            }
        }
```

Comment: No need to change from `ReadLines` to `ReadAllLines`. In fact `ReadLines` is preferred because it returns an IEnumerable<string> without loading all lines in memory. This is a big advantage when working with large files

Comment: @Chris this is the first time to notice that really sorry and yes i'm a beginner but thanks for your answer and your time

Comment: @Shannon Holsinger i've been searching google for hours now

Comment: @nabuchodonossor i did tried foreach but it came up with an error

Comment: If you get an error: What error? What line of Code? Did you replace the "..." with the appropriate values for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with LINQ:

```
var parts = File.ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt")  // No need to escape backslash here since you're using a verbatim string
    .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Length == 2 && p[0] == "ali");

if (parts != null)
{
    textBox1.Text = parts[0];
    textBox2.Text = parts[1];
}
```